# Continuous preserves compact sets, what about the converse?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, compactness

We know that if $f : X \rightarrow Y $ is a continuous function then image of every compact subset of X is compact in Y.  What if we try to prove the converse ? Clearly , image of compact set is compact won't be enough, but can we add other conditions to force the function to be continuous ?

Obviously adding conditions like "f is a homeomorphism" or any such condition which would clearly trivialize the problem won't be allowed.

**EDIT**
X and Y are metric spaces.

I was guessing that imposing the condition "X,Y are infinite and  every infinite compact set maps to infinite compact set " might be useful but I can't go any further.

Comment: There are some pretty bad examples. Let $X$ by an infinite set with the indiscrete topology, and let $Y$ denote the same set with the cofinite topology. Let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity map. Every subset of $X$ is compact, as is every subset of $Y$, and $f$ is certainly cardinality-preserving, but $f$ is far from being continuous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you know of any condition which would work ?

Comment: I’m afraid not, at least not off the top of my head. I’ll give it a little thought, but I suspect that there isn’t any very general condition that will work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I forgot to mention X and Y are metric spaces.